# Stocker Module Old Data

Tags: python, finance, stock

I have recently set up the stocker module on my computer through (https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/tree/master/stocker)

I have been testing various stocks and noticed the data only goes through `3/27/18`.
ie:

> microsoft = Stocker(ticker='MSFT')
>   output => **MSFT Stocker Initialized. Data covers 1986-03-13 00:00:00 to 2018-03-27 00:00:00.**

How do get it to update into realtime?